# Add class to element in MaterializeCss Slider on every slide change

Tags: jquery, materialize

Looking to add a class to a button when a slide is active in Materializecss.

```
 if ($("#slide-1").hasClass("active")) {
  $("#button").addClass('active');
 }
```

I want it to work on every slide change and not just once.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it

```
$('#carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({
    indicators: false,
    onCycleTo: function(data) {
        if ($(data).index() ==1) {
                $("#li-1").addClass("active");
            } else {
                $("#li-1").removeClass("active");
            }
        if ($(data).index() ==2) {
                $("#li-2").addClass("active");
            } else {
                $("#li-2").removeClass("active");
            }
     }
});
```